# Curl working on localhost but not working on server

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, php-curl

so here is my problem ... I have a php-curl function that sends a POST Request to an API with a file as a parameter.
My Code is working perfectly fine on the localhost and its not working on my server.

Server Details
 - Dedicated VPS windows server 2012
 - Installed PHP 5.5 and MySQL 5.5 and phpmyadmin
 - Curl is enabled ... && tried a simple curl function and its working fine
My app
 - My Code is working perfectly fine on localhost but its not working on the server (i tried multiple servers with multiple specs)

```
 $localFile=$_FILES['file_c']['tmp_name'];

    $curl = curl_init($url);

     if ((version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5') >= 0)) {
         $data = array(
            'version' => '2017-01-20',
            'file' => new CURLFile($localFile),

            'config'=> '{"conversion_target":"normalized_html"}'
        );
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true);
       }else{
        $data = array(
            'version' => '2017-01-20',
            'file' => "@".$localFile,

            'config'=> '{"conversion_target":"normalized_html"}'
        );
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, false);

    }



    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);  // Insert the data


    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);


    // Send the request
    if(!curl_exec($curl)){

    die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));

    }else{ //do something else}
```

so this piece of code works fine on localhost but on the server it shoots a 500 internal server error

no errors in server logs
I've traced every single line in that code it breaks at the curl execution line

Please help
Thanks!

Comment: Check curl extension is enable in live server....

Comment: check ip server , (block) .

Comment: @shibon, Curl is enabled

Comment: @Mohammad, what do u mean by check ip server ?

Comment: yes , It might be blocked. Another server test AND `echo curl_error($curl)` .

Comment: I've tried it from a different server with a different ip still the same issue exactly
also I've tried echoing the error
         if(!curl_exec($curl)){

    die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));

    }
but it breaks at the execution part